# How do i place 4 headers from 1 div next to each other?

Tags: css, html, web

I have a menu with four links, as H4 elements, plus an image. They are all in the same div with the class menu. How would I proceed, in CSS, to make all these form one line?

This is my html:

```
    <html>
    <head> <title>Testing menu</title> </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
        <a href="program.html"><h3>Program</h3></a>
        <a href="info.html"><h3>Informasjon</h3></a>
        <a href="aktiviteter.html"><h3>Aktiviteter</h3></a>
        <a href="kontakt.html"><h3>Kontakt</h3></a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What kind of CSS should I use to make all of the items in the div get next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/6ssD3/2/)**

use `display: inline-block;`

css

```
.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Following css Rule in your code:

```
.menu a { 

           float: left;
          padding: 10px;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inline-block`:

```
.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
      .menu a {
        display: inline-block;
      }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nq98y/1/)

css inline-block will help

```
  .menu a{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;

    }
```